# value won't update using if statement unless edited/submitted manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on slider that updates 2 text boxes with values, the slider is in a limited range so it doesn't give values lower/higher than min/max.

when you decide to update the values in the boxes manually it also updates the other box with correct value but when you enter a value out of the range it updates it to max/min allowed in that box but doesn't update the related value in the other box unless you go in the box and edit/click enter.

I want it to update the other box to min/max too when you enter a value out of the allowed range.

I know this is confusing, but for example put 50 in the CAD box, it updates the BTC to 0.04113, but if you put 200 in the CAD box it changes it to max allowed which is 99.99 but the BTC box stays at 0.16453 which is double than the allowed 0.08 BTC and does not update to the 99.99 equivalent value.

Any ideas/pointers on how to fix this?
https://jsfiddle.net/4o6ashpn/

(the js & css in the jsfiddle is for the slider only)

```
function bitcoinCheck(input) {
                        if (input.value < 0.002) input.value = 0.002;
                        if (input.value > 0.08) input.value = 0.08;
                    }
function cadCheck(input) {
                        if (input.value < 2) input.value = 2;
                        if (input.value >= 100) input.value = 99.99;
                    }
```

Comment: Appears to behave as expected, if not please take some time to restate the question more clearly.  Shoe an example of expected and actual behavior.

Comment: if you enter 200 for CAD it updates the value to 99.99 but doesn't update the BTC value to a99.99 equivalent, it stays at the 200 CAD equivalent value.

Comment: You need to call `recalc_cad()` inside `cadCheck()` after updating the value.

Comment: Strings are not numbers

Comment: @Barmar, when I'm calling it it doesn't work.

Comment: @epascarello, is that where the problem is?

Comment: Setting a value in JavaScript does not trigger a change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update the other field when you call `recalc_cad()` or `recalc_btc()`, which only happens in the `keyup` event, not when you leave the field and the `change` event occurs. You should put an additional call to those functions in the `bitcoinCheck()` and `cadCheck()` functions.

```js
var btcPrice = 1215.60;

function cad2btc(amount) {
  amount = parseFloat(amount);
  var btc = amount / btcPrice;
  return btc;
}

function btc2cad(amount) {
  amount = parseFloat(amount);
  var cad = amount * btcPrice;
  return cad;
}

function recalc_cad(amount) {
  cad = parseFloat(amount.value);
  var btc = cad2btc(cad);

  document.getElementById('amount_btc').value = btc.toFixed(5);
}

function recalc_btc(amount) {
  var btc = parseFloat(amount.value),
    cad = btc2cad(btc);
  document.getElementById('amount_cad').value = cad.toFixed(2);
}

function bitcoinCheck(input) {
  if (input.value < 0.002) input.value = 0.002;
  if (input.value > 0.08) input.value = 0.08;
  recalc_btc(input);
}

function cadCheck(input) {
  if (input.value < 2) input.value = 2;
  if (input.value >= 100) input.value = 99.99;
  recalc_cad(input);
}
```

```html
<input class="input-large" id="amount_btc" name="PAYMENT_AMOUNT_BTC" placeholder="You will receive BTC" pattern="^[0-9.]+$" onkeyup="recalc_btc(this);" onchange="bitcoinCheck(this);" required>

<input class="input-large" id="amount_cad" name="PAYMENT_AMOUNT" placeholder="Amount (CAD) - Minimum 1$" pattern="^[0-9.]+$" onkeyup="recalc_cad(this);" onchange="cadCheck(this);" required>
```

Comment: Oh, I should have passed input, just wrote recalc_btc(); no wonder it didn't work. Yours works beautifully! Thanks!